# Can I do this instead to prove the Strong Principle of Induction (Tao 2.2.14)?

Tags: foundations, peano-axioms

I have already read the [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307429/proof-of-strong-principle-of-induction-t-tao-analysis-i) ([this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499789/strong-induction-from-tao) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103897/how-to-prove-proposition-2-2-14-in-tao-analysis-i) too) discussions on Stack Exchange and they have not answered my query. Proposition 2.2.14 asks the reader to prove that:

**Proposition $2.2.14$** (Strong principle of induction). Let $m_0$ be 
a natural number, and let $P(m)$ be a property pertaining to an 
arbitrary natural number $m$. Suppose that for each $m \ge m_0$, we 
have the following implication: if $P(m')$ is true for all natural 
numbers $m_0 \leq m' < m$, then $P(m)$ is also true. (In particular, 
this means that $P(m_0)$ is true since in this case, the hypothesis is vacuous
.) Then we can conclude that $P(m)$ is true for all natural 
numbers $m\geq m_0.$ (Hint: define $Q(n)$ to be the property that $P(m)$ is true for all $m_0≤m<n;$ note that $Q(n)$ is vacuously true when $n<m_0.$)

Instead of what Tao suggests, can I let $Q(n)$ to be the property that $P(m)$ is true for all $m_0\le m<m_0+n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That would be saying exactly the same thing. Picking $m_0+n$ as the upper bound is the same as picking $n'=m_0+n$ as the upper bound like Tao suggested. Just a different way of writing it.